# How copy data from one table into another? PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Following problem there are 2 tables, "Daten" and "Server" in my Mysql DB called "csv" they both got "ServerID" inside them as a column. How can I copy the data in column "ServerID" from the table "Server" to "Daten".

I probably have to say the numbers in "Server" "ServerID" are AUTO-Increment.

The result I want is: in ServerID is a number and I want that number in the other table too.

I tried this but its only giving me: "111111111111111111111111111111111111"

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","THUNI","root","csv");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT ServerID FROM Server";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 //Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ($row["ServerID"]);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: To select a field from a table simply add `table.field`. In your case it's `SELECT Server.ServerID FROM Server`

Comment: If you want to "copy" them, you have to `Insert into table2 (field1, field2) VALUES ($row["field1"], $row["field2"])`. Withjout your DB it's difficult to help you proprely

Comment: @hearner you mean the name right?

Comment: you said you got 2 tables. Update your question by giving your tables with their name. What result are you supposed to have though?

Comment: Is there only `ServerID` in both tables ?

Comment: @hearner no there are other columns and enteries too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Server (ServerID)
SELECT ServerID FROM Daten;
```

That will insert into Server the ServerID from Daten

The correct way to copy datas from a table to another is :

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

In your script, it should be something like that

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","THUNI","root","csv");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="Insert into Server 
        Select * from Daten";
mysqli_query($con,$sql); // That inserts the data from Daten to Server

$query = "SELECT ServerID FROM Server";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); // You're selecting ServerID in Server

echo "The result are ". mysqli_fetch_array($result)['ServerID']; // It gives all ServerID from Server
```

Comment: Add `INSERT INTO Server (ServerID)
SELECT ServerID FROM Daten;` in a `mysqli_query` and it's done

Comment: is there any different when I am using auto-increment for the data in "Server" "ServerID"?

Comment: no difference on mysql, no. and... the "insert into...select" syntax is a LOT faster than doing it over php because everything will be done inside the mysql server, so no network transfer, no php overhead, no transfer back...

Comment: tho I would write it like: insert into table_a (field_a, field_b, field_c) select a, b, c from table_b

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu the problem is I have a php script which imports CSV Files and this is a part of that script. It has to work everytime I import a CSV thats why I use auto-increment

Comment: auto-increment means when you create a new row, it automaticaly creates ServerID. So you CANNOT insert ServerID in your table. Here is your problem

Comment: it automaticaly inserts a number that number should be the ID for the servername for example "avlrbrcl02a" --> 1; "avlrbrcl02b"--> 2; and so on

Comment: hope you know what I mean ^^

Comment: Yes but think about it, you want to add a number that must be incremented, so it doesn't work. Change in `integer` and it should work IF THERE ARE NO duplicates

Comment: but it has to add enteries automaticaly + the number

Comment: Do it in php then :) do update or in the insert then you put the right name

Comment: If the table columns match (ie, you are making an exact copy one table into another) this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone I did it, it was not that hard.
The solution are functions, with funcitons you can insert everything at the same time and thats what I wanted. A function could look like this:

```
Function getserverID($Servername)
{
    //Check if the entery is already in the DB
    //to provide double enteries
    $result = mysql_query("select * from Server where Servername = lower('$Servername')");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($Servername =="avlrbrcl03"){
    //echo ($num_rows);
    }
        //If it is not existing, create the entery  
        if($num_rows == 0){
            $import="INSERT into Server(Servername) values(lower('$Servername'))";
                mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
                $ID=mysql_insert_id();

                //and if existing save it as a variable
                }else{
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $ID= $row["ServerID"];
                    }

        return $ID;
}
```

If you have already done this you have to create a While Loop to import the datas.
This could look like this:

```
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
    $Storagetyp = getstoragetyp($_FILES['filename']['name']);
    $ServerID = getserverID($data[0]);
    $Datum = getdatumID($data[2]);

    //Check if there is already such a entry
    $result = mysql_query ("select * from Daten where ServerID = '$ServerID' and Speicherplatz = '$data[1]' and DatumID = '$Datum'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        //If it doesn't exist, import it
        if($num_rows == 0){
            $import="INSERT into Daten(Speicherplatz, DatumID, ServerID, Storagetyp) values('$data[1]','$Datum','$ServerID','$Storagetyp')";
                mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have same schema for both the table.

**table 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `email` (
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**table 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `email_table` (
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**your query in php code would be:**

```
insert into email_table (select * from email);
```

Let me know in case any query :)

Thanks
Amit

Comment: do I have to set both "ServerID" as primary key?

Comment: "ServerID" in "Server" uses auto_increment for the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to do it.

```
<?php 

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","THUNI");
mysql_select_db("csv",$con);

$sql="INSERT INTO  Daten (ServerID)
 SELECT ServerID FROM Server";
 mysql_query($sql); 
?>
```